# Suppress "discarded non-Unit value" warning

Tags: scala, compiler-warnings

I have added the scalac command line argument `-Ywarn-value-discard` to my build because this would have caught a subtle bug that I just found in my code. However, I now get some warnings for "discarded non-Unit value" that are about intentional discards, not bugs. How do I suppress those warnings?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You suppress these warning by explictly returning unit (that is `()`).
By example turn this:

```
def method1() = {
   println("Hello")
   "Bye"
}
def method2(): Unit = {
  method1() // Returns "Bye", which is implicitly discarded
}
```

into:

```
def method1() = {
   println("Hello")
   "Bye"
}
def method2(): Unit = {
  method1()
  () // Explicitly return unit
}
```

Comment: don't you discard _non-Unit value_ when calling `method1` in `method2`?

Comment: The first snippet illustrates a case that **does** trigger the warning (when `-Ywarn-value-discard` is enabled), so yes indeed in this case a non-unit value (the return value of `method1`) is discarded when calling `method1` in `method2`. The second snippet explicitly returns "unit" (in other words `()`), thereby removing the warning.

Comment: Note that the procedure syntax for `method2` is deprecated and will not work in Scala 3

Answer (score 27):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25779018/154770), you can also use the syntax `val _`, i.e.

```
def method2(): Unit = {
  val _ = method1()
}
```

But there is some dispute over whether this or the answer by @Régis is the preferred style.

Comment: Would be `method1() match { case _ => }` acceptable as well?

Comment: I had issue with this solution where you need for instance: `val _ = rdd1.unpersist()` and the line below it `val _ = rdd2.unpersist()` the compiler says that the value `_` have already been defined

Comment: @Wonay: Only the _last_ line of a method needs this treatment, so there is no need to turn the line above it into an assignment. In more detail: `-Ywarn-value-discard` does not issue warnings for merely ignoring non-Unit values. "Value discarding" as defined in [section 6.26.1](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#value-discarding) of the language spec is specifically about a value appearing _where Unit is expected_, for example as the return value of a method.

Comment: Ah ok, I think it is because I am using the one from ScalaStyle

Answer (score 10):

Now you can suppress value-discard warning via type ascription to `Unit` in [Scala 2.13](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/7563).

This is an example:

```scala
def suppressValueDiscard(): Unit =
  "": Unit
```

Comment: @nafg The `: Unit` can still suppress that warning in the Scala 2.13.2.
But this feature won't work in some cases like https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/7563#issuecomment-460419680. I guess you may experience the same cases, or you just find a bug in Scalac.