# scala actually suppress compiler warnings

Tags: scala, warnings, compiler-warnings, scalac

how can I actually suppress the compiler warning for:

```
discarded non-Unit value
[warn]     kryo.register(classOf[Foo])
```

The suggestion of [Suppress "discarded non-Unit value" warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415307/suppress-discarded-non-unit-value-warning) does not apply since the problem takes place outside of my own code.

## edit

compiler options are:

```
"-target:jvm-1.8",
  "-encoding",
  "UTF-8",
  "-feature",
  "-unchecked",
  "-deprecation",
  "-Xfuture",
  "-Xlint:missing-interpolator",
  "-Yno-adapted-args",
  "-Ywarn-dead-code",
  "-Ywarn-numeric-widen",
  "-Ywarn-value-discard",
  "-Ywarn-dead-code",
  "-Ywarn-unused"
```

which will warn `"-Ywarn-value-discard",`

Comment: It might help if you specified the compiler/linter options you use, but I would try `val _ = kryo.register(classOf[Foo])`

Comment: your suggestion does not work as multiple calls to the function `kryo.register(classOf[Foo])
    kryo.register(classOf[Bar])` will fail then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just return `Unit` explicitly from the block where you call `kryo.register`. If there is no block, wrap it in one:

```
{
  kryo.register(classOf[Foo])
  kryo.register(classOf[Bar])
  () // I know what I'm doing
}
```

#### About warning suppression in general

Unfortunately Scala has no built-in suppression system. People [have been asking for this](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/7934) but it's not trivial to achieve. For now there are two options:

1. Disable the warning entirely
2. Use a compiler plugin: [silencer](https://github.com/ghik/silencer)