# Running test case in Scala gives "discarded non-Unit value"

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

I am newbie to scala

My sbt version is : **0.13.17**

My Scala version is : **Scala code runner version 2.12.6 -- Copyright 2002-2018, LAMP/EPFL and Lightbend, Inc.**

I am trying to run the test case with the following code

```
class TestSpec extends WordSpec with Matchers with MockFactory with OneAppPerSuite {

  "it" should {
    "add 2 numbers" in new Testing() {
      val a = 2
      val b = 3
      val expected = 5
      val result: Int = add(2, 3)

      result shouldEqual expected
    }
  }

  trait Testing {

    def add(a: Int, b: Int): Int = {
      a + b
    }
  }
}
```

And i get the following error

```
discarded non-Unit value
 "add 2 numbers" in new Testing() {
```

In my build.sbt file i see this

"-Ywarn-value-discard", // Warn when non-Unit expression results are unused

I cant remove the above line and how do i make sure my test case executes.

I have gone through this link 
[Suppress "discarded non-Unit value" warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415307/suppress-discarded-non-unit-value-warning). But not sure what needs to be done.
Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: If this is just a warning, are your tests still running? Or is this actually stopping your tests from working?

Comment: @JamesWhiteley My tests are stopped. I get an Error not a warning

Answer (score 1):

```
I just tried something like ... And it works.

class Testclass extends  FlatSpec with Matchers  with TestTrait {
  it should "add two integers" in  {
      val a: Int =  2
      val b: Int =  3
      val result = add(a, b)
      result shouldEqual(5)
    }
}

trait TestTrait {
  def add(a: Int, b: Int):Int = {
     a + b
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This warning arises because the assigned values a and b are not used. Maybe you meant to write:

```
val result: Int = add(a, b)
```

Answer (score -1):

***disable*** **-Ywarn-value-discard** in scalacOptions