# How to detect untracked future?

Tags: scala, future, static-analysis

Futures are executed in my code and are not being detected.

```
def f(): Future[String] = {
  functionReturningFuture() // How to detect this?
  Future("")
}
```

Ideally, a static analysis tool would help detect this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415307/suppress-discarded-non-unit-value-warning

Comment: @ViktorKlang as far as I remember `-Ywarn-value-discard` doesn't work if you return (without discarding) some non-`Unit` value, e.g. another `Future` as in example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closer you can get is [`NonUnitStatements`](https://www.wartremover.org/doc/warts.html#nonunitstatements) wart from WartRemover, but it cannot error only `Future` statements and skip all the others.

The fact that you have such issue could be used as an argument against using `Future` and replacing it with some IO: Cats' `IO`, Monix's `Task` or Scalaz Z`IO`. When it comes to them, you build your pipeline first, and the you run it. If you omitted `IO` value in return and you didn't compose it into the result in any other way (`flatMap`, `map2`, `for` comprehension etc) it would *not* get executed - it would still be there but it would cause no harm.

If you wanted to have greater control and error only on `Future`, you would probably have to write [your own WartRemover's wart](https://www.wartremover.org/doc/adding-your-own-warts.html) or [ScalaFix rule](https://scalacenter.github.io/scalafix/docs/developers/tutorial.html).